# Assign obj to a list empty list by name and using variable

Tags: r, list

I've constructed an empty list but with names, something like this:

```
lvls = letters[1:5]
tree <- tree <- vector("list", length(lvls))
names(tree) <- lvls
```

Now I'd like to assign an obj, in this case another list, to each of the names in the list, but using variables in a loop. I have this:

```
for(l in lvls){
  tree[[l]] <- vector("list", 5)
}
```

But it assigns to indices instead of by name. What I need is something like:

for(l in lvls){
  tree$l <- vector("list", 5)}

But this won't work, b/c the `l` is taken as a literal instead of a variable. Anyone know how I could change that?

**EDIT:**

I don't have a thorough grasp of R data structures. But it looks like the assignment format I used does work, only that assigning a list to the extension names was problematic.

```
for(l in lvls){
  tree[[l]] <- "test_string"
}
```

The above code does assign similar to `tree$var_name`, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear the output you need, when using this loop:

```
for (l in lvls){ 
 tree[[l]] <- vector("list", 5)
}
```

produces the a list of five lists

```
$a
$a[[1]]
NULL

$a[[2]]
NULL

$a[[3]]
NULL

$a[[4]]
NULL

$a[[5]]
NULL
 ....
```